# How to integrate the Google Speech Recognition API in a Webpage?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, ogg, google-cloud-platform

I want to use the Google Speech Recognition API [Google Speech API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize) into a Webpage by sending the request directly from the browser to Google.

Test requests using base64 encodes sample files already worked.
I am trying to use https://github.com/higuma/ogg-vorbis-encoder-js to record a ogg and send it to the API.

The request itself is done by a simple ajax request.

Did anybody implement it already in a web-browser (I also need iOS support, which should be possible since Safari recently updated and now supports recording)?

At the moment i am a bit stuck since the api just answers "{}"

Comment: I'm in the same boat at the moment. Any luck?